# I broke 200 upvote rep/day!

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

I appear to have earned 202 rep from upvotes today.

> [image: Daily rep]
>
> [image: +2 breakdown]

...so how exactly did I earn that +2? Today, I have not downvoted nor been downvoted, to the best of my knowledge.

EDIT: Reputation audit shows:

```
-- 2014-08-15 rep +260  = 57781
```

so I didn't actually get +2. What's going on, then?

Comment: What does your rep-audit page show?

Comment: @Mysticial: good call. rep-audit page is normal (260 as expected).

Comment: I'm going to guess that someone downvoted you then quickly removed the downvote at some recent point so the system hasn't yet caught up.

Comment: ...but the system correctly "caught up" on the rep-audit page?

Comment: Hypothesis: 1) Hit the repcap. 1) Get downvote (-2). 2) Get upvote (+2). 3) Remove downvote. This cancels out both downvote entries.

Comment: Mind if I actually test my hypothesis on you?

Comment: @nneonneo I very well may be wrong but I believe that page does not update as quickly as your reputation page. I'm not sure, just throwing out a possibility.

Comment: @Mysticial No, go right on ahead. Let me know if you need a helper.

Comment: FYI, the reputation system is [super complicated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237082/163250). Probably not a bug, just confusing as hell.

Comment: So I'm wrong... It had no effect on your rep page. But I managed to drop your visible rep. lol

Comment: @Cupcake: fk, that really is complicated. Ugh

Comment: @Mysticial: my rep page went back to exactly what it showed before.

Comment: @Mysticial: wait what did my visible rep say before? Right now it says 57,781, and that's what it's been saying (for me) for a few hours.

Comment: I think I repeated the process several times. And now your rep is showing 57771 instead of 57781. But it still says 262 for today...

Comment: @Mysticial: yeah now it says 57771 for me too. You broke it! :P Even better: my Meta rep and main rep are now out of sync.

Comment: Looks like I found a way to reduce Jon Skeet's visible rep to zero...

Comment: The devs are gonna be soooo pissed at me when they see the vote logs...

Comment: @nneonneo Your Meta reputation is only updated once an hour.

Comment: This happens to me regularly; it'll all self-correct in a few hours. It happens when you get downvoted, reach the cap with compensating upvotes, then get an un-downvote. Nothing to worry about, move along.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Mysticial tried that and it didn't seem to work...

Comment: @nneonneo: I had this yesterday; downvoted before the rep cap hit, undownvoted after. When I posted the comment my rep was still 2 points off the correct amount; that has since autocorrected.

Comment: @nneonneo: looking at my [rep history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation&sort=time&StartDate=2014-08-16%2008:37:22Z) some more, I realise there was an un-downvote on a post downvoted *the day before*. So on Thursday a post was downvoted (but I hit the cap anyway and was compensated), then un-downvoted the next day *after* hitting the cap. I was also downvoted during the day, got compensated, and I downvoted an answer at some point. I ended the day on 275,216 rather than the correct 275,218.

Answer (score 10):

There was a downvote on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25334219/105971) that put you at 198 reputation, followed by an upvote that gave you the +2 to bring you back to the daily cap. The downvote was later retracted by the user who cast it.

So now if you look at your rep history, you'll see that you just have +260 for that day - the normal 200 + four accepts at +15 each. No bug here, just a confusing timeline and a somewhat hard to read display.

Comment: Yeah, it looks right now. At the time it was incorrect.